# Until when a new package is considered by MikTeX to be "experimental"

Tags: packages, miktex

I have been searching for package "novel" on MikTeX package manager, that was recently announced by its author. Today I discovered that it is listed under the "experimental packages" option of MikTeK pakage manager.

Since the package "novel" seems well thought and documented, I get curious up to when a new package is considered stable to exclude it from the "experimental packages" list.

If moderators consider this question as non applicable to the topic of this group, proceed to close the question.

Comment: Miktex doesn't evaluate the quality of such packages. If the package was marked as experimental (I can't confirm this after a synchronization today) then it was either an error or the maintainer simply needed a bit time to catch up (he seemed to have been away the last weeks) and put everything new as a first step in the experimental stage.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, many thanks for your clarifying answer.

Comment: I am the author of the novel package. Indeed well thought and documented. But recently, changes in other supporting packages cause it to crash (it did not crash before). I have withdrawn the package, rather than maintain it by chasing changes to other TeX code.